# How to get the explicit example of existence from Reduce?

Tags: equation-solving, exists

I have the following Reduce:

```
A = {{a1, a2}, {a3, a4}};
B = {{b1, b2}, {b3, b4}};
     Reduce[u < 0 && v < 0 && x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0 && z^2 - 4 u v > 0 &&
       Exists[{a1, a2, a3, a4, b1, b2, b3, b4}, 
       a1 > 0 && a2 > 0 && a3 > 0 && a4 > 0 && b1 > 0 && b2 > 0 && 
        b3 > 0 && b4 > 0, 
       Tr[A] == x && Tr[B] == y && Tr[A . B] == z &&
        Det[A] == u && 
        Det[B] == v], {x, y, z, u, v}, Reals]
```

If you run this it will prove that these conditions on $x=Tr(A),y=Tr(B),z=Tr(A.B),u=Det(A),v=Det(B)$ is sufficient for existence of matrices $A,B$ with positive entries that satisfy the above. Since Reduce can show Existance, my hope is that it can now algebraically find these $A,B$ in terms of $x,y,z,u,v$.

I tried utilizing solve but

```
Assuming[
 Simplify[
  Solve[Tr[A] == x && Tr[B] == y && Tr[A . B] == z &&
    
    Det[A] == u && Det[B] == v, {a1, a2, a3, a4, b1, b2, b3, b4}, 
   PositiveReals]], 
 u < 0 && v < 0 && x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0 && z^2 - 4 u v > 0]
```

Does not work as it first solves the system and then uses assumptions I presume, in any case the computation does not halt as quickly as Reduce. Any help would be appriciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Ask for the variables of interest and get rid of all the rest

```
A = {{a1, a2}, {a3, a4}};
B = {{b1, b2}, {b3, b4}};
Reduce[Det[A]<0 && Det[B]<0 && Tr[A.B]^2-4 Det[A]Det[B]>0 &&
  Tr[A]>0 && Tr[B]>0 && Tr[A.B]>0 &&
  a1>0 && a2>0 && a3>0 && a4>0 && b1>0 && b2>0 && b3>0 && b4>0,
  {a1,a2,a3,a4,b1,b2,b3,b4}]
```

which instantly returns the set of solutions

```
a1>0 && a2>0 && a3>0 && 0<a4<a2 a3/a1 && 
b1>0 && b2>0 && b3>0 && 0<b4<b2 b3/b1
```

Test this brutally before you even think of trusting this.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question or I perhaps explained wrong. In simpler terms, I have the following conditions $u < 0 && v < 0 && x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0 && z^2 - 4 u v > 0$ where $x,y,z,u,v$ are defined as in the post. I want Mathematica to algebraically find $a1,a2,a3,a4,b1,b2,b3,b4$ (in terms of $x,y,z,u,v$ ) such that the positive matrices $A,B$ fit the parameters $x,y,z,u,v$

Comment: Let's check this CAREFULLY, you must not trust me. You defined `Det[A]==u&&u<0` I replaced that with `Det[A]<0` And the same with `v,x,y,z`. If you go through your post and replace all your `u,v,x,y,z` with what you defined those to be do you get EXACTLY what I got? Are all my eliminations of variables precisely correct? Can we identify any specific error that I made?

Comment: I think I see the issue here. I begin with $x,y,z,u,v$ which are just some variables with some constraints on them, namely the ones in the comment above. After we fix these variables we want to exhibit $a1,a2,a3,a4,b1,b2,b3,b4$ all positive such that $Tr(A)=x,Tr(B)=y,...$ etc.

Comment: +1 for both. I have a similar need, and am watching closely.

Comment: I am trying to find a way to express your problem that does what I think you want.  I've tried replacing `Det` and `Tr` with their definitions, but not eliminated your `x,y,z,u,v`. Try this `Reduce[a1+a4==x&&b1+b4==y&&a1 b1+a3 b2+a2 b3+a4 b4==z&&-a2 a3+a1 a4==u&&-b2 b3+b1 b4==v, {a1,a2,a3,a4,b1,b2,b3,b4}]/.{a2==0->False,a2!=0->True,a3==0->False,a3!=0->True,b2==0->False,b2!=0->True}` That still doesn't include some of your constraints and isn't what I want, but I haven't yet found what I'm looking for.

Comment: So this is on the right track and I got similar results with solve. Now taking the result of the reduce above we essentially want to find positive $a1,a2,b1$ such that all the other variables given by the Reduce are also positive. The existence of such $a1,a2,b1$ is guaranteed by the conditions I give, but I need to find them explicitly if possible. Thank you!

Comment: If we use your reduce and force eveything to be positive like here: `Simplify[Reduce[(-a1^2-u+a1x)/a2>0&&-a1+x>0&&-((2a1b1-b1x-a1y+xy-z-Sqrt[4a3(a2b1^2+a2v-a2b1y)+(-2a1b1+b1x+a1y-xy+z)^2])/(2a3))>0&&(-b1^2-v+b1y)/b2>0&&-b1+y>0&&a1>0&&a2>0&&b1>0&&a3>0&&b2>0,{a1,a2,b1,b2,a3},Reals],u<0&&v<0&&x>0&&y>0&&z>0&&z^2-4uv>0]` we actaully get conditions on that make it true. Now i need Mathematica to find a single instance when this is true where $a1,a2...$ depend only on $x,y,z,u,v$

Comment: I believe your system is underdetermined. To confirm that I pick acceptable a1,a2,b1,b2 and then ask it to find everything else based on your conditions. `Reduce[a1==1&&a2==3/2&&b1==1&&b2==3/2&&a1+a4==x&&b1+b4==y&&a1 b1+a3 b2+a2 b3+a4 b4==z&&-a2 a3+a1 a4==u&&-b2 b3+b1 b4==v, {a1,a2,a3,a4,b1,b2,b3,b4}]` and it does not respond that there is no such solution.  The only part of that result that worries me a little is `u==-v+x y-z` Is that condition part of your system or did my constants introduce that? Please check all this very carefully to try to make certain that I have not made any mistakes.

Comment: @Bill I am almost certain that the system is in fact underdetermined. There will not be a unique solution. I am not looking for a specific solution just a solution. I think your constants introduced this relationship you mention.  Let `A = {{1, 3/2}, {a3, a4}} B = {{1, 3/2}, {b3, b4}}` Then direct computation shows that $u==-v+x y-z$ this condition is not inherent to my conditions.

Comment: For example let $x=17/2,y=8/5,z= 479/5,u=-(44/5),v=-(87/10)$ These numbers satisfy my conditions, therefore positive matrices A,B exist s.t $x=Tr(A),y=Tr(B),z=Tr(A.B),u=Det(A),v=Det(B)$. FindInstance does quick work of this (it even finds it exactly but I round the result) `{{a1 -> 0.143603, a2 -> 10., a3 -> 1., a4 -> 8.3564, b1 -> 1.23116, 
  b2 -> 1., b3 -> 9.1541, b4 -> 0.368841}}`